# How to connect to multiple websocket servers with vue-socket.io-extended

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, socket.io, vue-socket.io

I have 2 servers A and B. Each running on a different port. How do I connect to both servers in Vuejs using `vue-socket.io-extended`?

What I have tried so far is:

```js
import store from './store'
import VueSocketIOExt from 'vue-socket.io-extended'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

Vue.use(VueSocketIOExt, io('http://localhost:4000'), { store })
Vue.use(VueSocketIOExt, io('http://localhost:5000'), { store })
```

The above code does connect both instances of our `vue-socket.io-extended` client to their respective servers, but events and emits only work for the client that was first registered.

The code below is what I have in my VueComponent:

```js
export default {
  ...
  sockets: {
        serverA_event(state){
            // do something ...
        },

        serverB_event(state){
            // do something ..
        }
  },
  ...
}
```

Note: I would like to use `vue-socket.io-extended` to do something similar to what is done in the example [here](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io/pull/98) with `vue-socket.io`. I tried using `vue-socket.io` but for some reason, I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: See plugin source  vue-socket.io-extended: [link](https://github.com/probil/vue-socket.io-extended/blob/master/src/plugin.js#L63)


Especially this line :
`Vue.prototype.$socket = $socket;`

It seems like only one instance of socket.io can be injected into Vue app through this plugin, or you need two instances of Vue.